# How to represent PHI formula in PHP

Tags: php, math, formula

I'm trying to use this formula in PHP code, But I can't find a way to represent it.

```
phi = (A+B)/A = A/B
```

Say I have a number:

```
$a = 275;
```

I want the value of $b to be in the golden ratio with relation to $a;
I know I can find the PHI constant by:

```
$phi = (1+sqrt(5))/2;
```

I don't know how to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you have mentioned in your question, the formula of `phi` is `(a+b)/a = a/b`
and you have the value of the `phi` from `(1+sqrt(5))/2`

if you have the value of `a`, then you can find the value of b derived from `phi = a/b` to be `b = phi/a`

in PHP that would be

```
define('PHI', (1+sqrt(5))/2);

function goldenRatio($num){
    return PHI/$num;
}

var_dump(goldenRatio(1)); // returns 0.618033989
var_dump(goldenRatio(2)); // returns 1.236067977
var_dump(goldenRatio(3)); // returns 1.854101966
```

Comment: Thank you  for your quick response.